# How to scale a UIWebview properly

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, scale

I have a UIWebView that I want to resize using a "scale" factor, lets say, 0.65. So what I want to do is multiply both width and height of the webview ( that, in the beginning, is equal to the screen width and height)  for this scale (0.65), so it will become smaller than the screen. Is there anyway to do that and make sure that the webview will maintain the proportions when I rotate it to landscape?
Here's what I am doing rigth now. It works fine when I am only in portrait mode, but it turn into a huge mess when I turn it to landscape mode.

webview.delegate = self;
    webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _adView.frame.size.width * _scale, _adView.frame.size.height * _scale);

```
webview.center = CGPointMake(_adView.frame.size.width/2, _adView.frame.size.height/2);
webview.bounds = webview.frame;
webview.opaque = NO;
webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your frame during orientation change?

```
   - (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
    {
        [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

            // Update your views here

        } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        }];

        [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
```